# How to eliminate duplicate key value pair inside a list

Tags: python

```
[
    {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, 
    {'date': '08/17/2016', 'duration': 5.0}, 
    {'date': '08/01/2016', 'duration': 5.2}, 
    {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, 
    {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, 
    {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}
]
```

if data is like that.

Comment: Please show what you have done yourself. Read how to put together a [mcve] to help guide you.

Answer (score 2):

One easy but not really efficient solution can be:

```
a = [{'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/17/2016', 'duration': 5.0}, {'date': '08/01/2016', 'duration': 5.2}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}]
b = []
for c in a:
   if c in b:
      continue
   b.append(c)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`FrozenDict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict). By using this, you may perform set like operation on your `dict`. But this not available as default python package.

Alternatively, Make entry from your list to new list and make a check before entering the new value. Below is the sample code:

```
my_list = [{'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/17/2016', 'duration': 5.0}, {'date': '08/01/2016', 'duration': 5.2}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}]

new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if item not in new_list:
        new_list.append(item)

# new_list = [{'date': '08/11/2016', 'duration': 13.0}, {'date': '08/17/2016', 'duration': 5.0}, {'date': '08/01/2016', 'duration': 5.2}]
```